# Adding numbers from a file

Tags: c#

What i want to do is read the numbers from the file text.txt, and add them together
the file contains

```
86
97 
144 
26
```

All on their own line. I am stumped :L

This is my code:

```
namespace CH13EX1
{
    class CH13EX1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // opens the file
            StreamReader inFile;
            // tests to make sure the file exsits
            if (File.Exists("text.txt"))
            {
                // declrations
                string inValue;
                int total;
                int number;
                // makes infile the file 
                inFile = new StreamReader("text.txt");
                // loop to real the files
                while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    number = int.Parse(inValue);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are stumped on which lines of code?

Comment: A lot of experts here could just *give* you the answer but I feel like that wouldn't help you in the long run. It looks like you've done all the difficult parts. What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3):

A minimal change to your existing code is

```
int total = 0;
using(inFile = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
{
    while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {   
        if(Int32.TryParse(inValue, out number))
        {
             total += number;
             Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - not a number", inValue);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum is  {0}", total);
```

Of course, the value read from the file should be added to a variable that holds the running total of the values on the single lines, but I have added a [more secure way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to check if your numbers are really integer numbers (Parse will raise an exception if it could not convert the string to an integer value).

Also I have used the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to open the file and ensure a correct way to close and dispose the StreamReader

Comment: Ty, Thank solves my problem, and i appreciate the extra information :D

Comment: Can also improve by using the simple `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` to avoid any `Stream` stuff.